# Sending value from Arduino to MySQL using ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am trying to send a value from Arduino to a remote MySQL. I am following [this tutorial](http://bryceautomation.com/index.php/2016/12/24/logging-data-to-web-page-using-arduino-and-esp8266-01-at-command-set/).

I have tried but no data is received on the server. What is the issue? I am new to Arduino. My code is:

```
int led1=8;
int count=1;
void setup() {
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  delay(3000);
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CWJAP=\"mhboys\",\"mhboys123\"");
  delay(1000);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led1,HIGH);
  // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);  // wait for a second
  if(digitalRead(led1)==LOW) {}
  if(digitalRead(led1)==HIGH) {
    count++;
    //code for sending updated count to mysql
  }
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000); // wait for a second
  int adjustedValue = count;
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"www.onemediagroup.in\",80");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSEND=66");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("GET /energy/getUsage.php?currentValue=");
  Serial.print(adjustedValue);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(100000); // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

Comment: You must post your code. We cannot tell what you are doing wrong unless you show your work.

Comment: I am not getting any data in my server.

Comment: The wifi module does not blink the blue light. Is it any issue?

Answer (score 2):

You're sending commands blindly without checking if they actually succeeded. If you're not ready to correctly handle the responses, you're better off using a library like [this](https://github.com/itead/ITEADLIB_Arduino_WeeESP8266). The 'HTTP GET' example should help.